# pyside qcombobox not styling properly

Tags: python, pyside, qcombobox, qtstylesheets

I have a qtcombobox. I'm attempting to add some styling using a qss stylesheet and it's not rendering properly. The white background you see below is unwanted.

Picture:

[image: qcombobox_image]

My code to style it:

```
QWidget
{
    color: #eff0f1;
    background-color: #31363b;
    selection-background-color:#3daee9;
    selection-color: #eff0f1;
    background-clip: border;
    border-image: none;
    border: 0px transparent black;
    outline: 0;
}


QComboBox
{
    selection-background-color: #3daee9;
    border-style: solid;
    border: 1px solid #76797C;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    min-width: 75px;
}

QComboBox:hover,QPushButton:hover,QAbstractSpinBox:hover,QLineEdit:hover,QTextEdit:hover,QPlainTextEdit:hover,QAbstractView:hover,QTreeView:hover
{
    border: 1px solid #3daee9;
    color: #eff0f1;
}

QComboBox:on
{
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    selection-background-color: #4a4a4a;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView
{
    background-color: #232629;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #76797C;
    selection-background-color: #3daee9;
}

QComboBox::drop-down
{
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 15px;

    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-left-color: darkgray;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow
{
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/down_arrow_disabled.png);
}

QComboBox::down-arrow:on, QComboBox::down-arrow:hover,
QComboBox::down-arrow:focus
{
    image: url(:/qss_icons/rc/down_arrow.png);
}
```

What can cause the inner most portion to remain white?
For what it's worth, the dropdown menu is styling properly. Not sure what's messing with it to make part of the bg white.

Edit: So I've created a little test case with this stylesheet and the bare minimum and the qcombobox works there. There's a lot of code that touches this qcombobox so something else is probably messing with it but I wouldn't know where to start or how narrow it down. Any hints/ suggestions are greatly appreciated. I've tried commenting out other setstylesheet commands and obvious basics like that.

Comment: You're the only one that can see the code, so I guess this is your opportunity to learn some basic debugging techniques. Start by commenting out all the stylesheets, and then add them back one by one. It's really not that complicated.

Comment: @ekhumoro My edit mentions that I already commented out the other stylesheets and that I still get that behavior. I was wondering if there's a name for the text for the button. Not the dropdown list. qcombobox is composed of several different elements. If I can find that name, I might be able to search the code for something that might be modifying the style in a different way other than calling setstylesheet.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow comletely missed that part. If the combo-box is editable, it will contain a `QLineEdit`, so probably something is changing the styling of that.

Comment: Thank you! That field is editable. Adding a red bg to both QLineEdit and QLineEdit:hover will turn the black bg portion red only on hover but not that inner white portion. It's still white. Any more suggestions?

Comment: For me on Windows it works. I would prefer a minimal example and running system specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, stylesheet rules do not seem to cascade to line-edits in a combo-box. The only solution seems to be to apply the stylesheet directly:

```
self.combo.lineEdit().setStylesheet('background-color: red')
```

That may not work with all widget-styles, though (for example, it doesn't seem to work with the "Windows" style).

**EDIT**:

Here is what I used for testing:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Test', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.combo = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.combo.setEditable(True)
        self.edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QWidget
            {
            background-color: yellow;
            }
            QComboBox
            {
            background-color: blue;
            }
            QLineEdit
            {
            background-color: red;
            }
            """)

    def handleButton(self):
        self.combo.lineEdit().setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 200, 300, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here are the results I get on Linux:

[image]

Clicking the "Test" button does set the background of the combo line-edit. I also tried some other selectors like `QComboBox > QLineEdit`, `QLineEdit#foobar`, etc - but none of them have any effect.

Comment: The code I'm working with was indeed tampering with the lineedit. This line of code does fix my issue but I'd rather not mess around with manually managing colors. These lines reload the styles.

Comment: `self.view.style().unpolish(self.view)`
`self.view.style().polish(self.view)`
`self.view.update()`

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: "For some reason, stylesheet rules do not seem to cascade to line-edits in a combo-box." Hm, just tried. For me they seem to cascade. Have you checked that they don't?

Comment: @Trilarion. Of course. I've added some example code to my answer - but maybe I'm missing something obvious.